# Code gen OData server-side code from Entity Framework context?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, odata

I have a model and a database context that I scaffolded from SQL Server using Entity Framework.  I would now like to expose this entire model via OData.  Is this possible?  If so, how do I do it?  Alternatively, can I expose SQL Server data via OData directly?

It's very easy to expose one entity at a time, building the controller, etc., but it seems to me there should be a way to do it for the whole context at once.  My model has dozens of tables - I don't want to have to hand-roll each one!

Also, I didn't have to do that for the old "ADO.NET Data Services", which this project is meant to replace.  I'd like to think modern tools would be even better, not a step back. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is totally possible and quite trivial, though I would strongly suggest NOT exposing Entity Framework classes directly but using a separat emodel and using i.e. automapper (mostly automapper) to map the results - that way you are not bound to the definition and naming of the entity framework classes, which i.e. may include a lot of internal fields.

> It's very easy to expose one entity at a time, building the controller, etc.,
> but it seems to me there should be a way to do it for the whole context at
> once

Not really - because that makes no sense in a lot of scenarios, i.e. you assume you want to expose all the data. Let me specify that for QUERYING that is basically a copy/paste operation per class and the mappings for automapper, if you use it.

> My model has dozens of table

This is a SMALLER model, as far as enterprise models go.

There is no proper code generator that i know of - or would use because I have some base classes that do a lot of additional processing and evaluating (i.e. query cost - expansions can kill your server unless you limit the amounts done).

> I'd like to think modern tools would be even better, not a step back. :)

There are a lot of people that do not believe in odata - mostly that is the result of a tremendous lack of real knowledge. The result of that - and a focus on the way worse services like RESTier which basically is "primitive odata without the tooling and even basic services like proper filtering and expansion" plus GRPC (which is even funnier - small spec because hey, a lot is just not even covered, so yeah, if you do not specify a query language that part is not in the spec) mean that the focus is on less toolable stuff. Given that most people do not even know that Odata can be properly accessed and queried from Excel, i.e. - well, that is what you get.

But again, I would not, never ever, expose EF classes directly in Odata - I always run them in at least 3 projects: A Data model with the repositor, an ApiModel project with the classes for the OData layer and the API project with the Automapper classes. Given that I have 3 base classes (depending on whether an entity is Code keyed (string), int keyed or guid keyed - that is just a simple copy operation, define in model etc. - yes, it is a little nasty, but you get a LOT more flexibility.

Comment: "But again, I would not, never ever, expose EF classes directly in Odata " to an external consumer, I mostly agree.  But as a component of a single solution, it's appropriate.  Also where the EF model is purpose-built to publish data, and doesn't leak a bunch of application internals.

Comment: Even internal never. See, the problem is that the database may have a rework or fields added - I do not want that out via odata. Also, you can easily do propjections or calcualted fields - not possible if you directly expose. Not sure you CAN purpose build an Ef Model without exposing internal details that may not be - but then my databases look likely different than yours.

Comment: You can do a lot at the EF layer to translate the database schema to something else.  Renaming tables, and columns, omitting columns, using views, table splitting, etc.  Most of the same things you could do with a client-side mapper, but with the transformations translated to SQL.

Comment: Hence Isay automapper - does that. I generally never do a specific EF framework layer for only presentation - I keep that automated to the database as much as possible.

Comment: Which is a fine choice.  But if you do a consumer-ready EF model, RESTier is the easiest way to publish it to web consumers.

Comment: Unless RESTier is changed al ot form when I looked at it (ages ago) it is "one lass to rule them all". Reading only that is already stretching it - the moment you do anything else, that is a LOT of methods on that one class.

Comment: I'm no expert on it, but here's the doc: https://github.com/OData/RESTier/blob/main/docs/msdocs/server/model-building.md

Comment: Whereas "it is totally possible and quite trivial" sounds promising, I don't see any information in that post about HOW (apart from the approach I already suggested). :)

Comment: "I would strongly suggest NOT exposing Entity Framework classes directly" - I understand what you're saying, but that's a bit of a distraction, since it doesn't actually address the issue and it is very situation-dependent.  For example our database structure is such that the database I'll be exposing is already an abstraction layer created specifically to shield the developers from any changes to the underlying structure of the databases containing the data. :)  But getting into that discussion is tangential to the question I'm asking.